# Error in Prosses <proc_num> with exit value:

Tags: parallel-processing, erlang

I'm trying to parallelize a function but I seem to be having problems (in Erlang).

I have code similar to this:

```
-module(examples).
-import(lists, [sublist/2, sublist/3]).

motherFunc(Ls) -> childFunc(Ls, false).

childFunc(Ls, false) ->
    Pid1 = spawn(example, mergesortP, [lists:sublist(Ls, length(Ls) div 2, self()]),
    Pid2 = spawn(example, mergesortP, [lists:sublist(Ls, length(Ls) div 2, self()]),
    FirstHalf = [],
    SecondHalf = [],
    receive
        {Pid1, Msg} -> FirstHalf = Msg;
        {Pid2, Msg} -> SecondHalf = Msg
end,
SecondHalf ++ FirstHalf;
childFunc([], Pid) -> Pid ! {self(), []};
childFunc([L], Pid) -> Pid ! {self(), [L]};
childFunc(Ls, Pid) -> 
    Pid1 = spawn(examples, childFunc, [lists:sublist(Ls, length(Ls) div 2, self()]),
    Pid2 = spawn(examples, childFunc, [lists:sublist(Ls, length(Ls) div 2 + 1, length(Ls) div 2 + 1), self()]),
    FirstHalf = [],
    SecondHalf = [],
    receive
        {Pid1, Msg} -> FirstHalf = Msg;
        {Pid2, Msg} -> SecondHalf = Msg
    end,
    Pid ! {self(), SecondHalf ++ FirstHalf}.
```

When I run this I'm getting this error message for both threads, and then it does nothing else: `Error in process <0.31.0> with exit value: {undef,[{examples,childFunc,[[1,2,3,4],<0.2.0>],[]}]}`

Comment: Are you calling the function from within the same module?  If not, try adding `-export([childFunc/2]).` to the top of the file.

Comment: Yes, but I tried that too.

Comment: How are you calling `childFunc/2`? Is it only from within the same module or from other modules?

Comment: From within the same module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `spawn/3` with the module and the function name as the first and second argument requires that the function is exported.

In fact, any explicit qualified call:

```
module:function(...)
```

or implicit qualified call:

```
apply(module, function, ...)
```

requires that the function be exported. Whether it's supposedly from the same module or not is irrelevant (1).

In your code, you should either use `spawn/1` or export the function:

```
-export([childFunc/2, mergesortP/2]).

% ...

spawn(?MODULE, mergesortP, [lists:sublist(Ls, length(Ls) div 2), self()])
```

or

```
Self = self(),
spawn(fun() -> mergesortP(lists:sublist(Ls, length(Ls) div 2), Self) end.
```

Note the difference when passing `self()`. With `spawn/3` invocation, `self()` is evaluated by the spawning process and therefore is its pid. If you call `self()` within the anonymous function passed to `spawn/1`, it will evaluate to the pid of the spawned process. So you need to call it before and pass it in a variable.

**Additionally, your code is unlikely to work**. Indeed, the following section does not do what you mean:

```
FirstHalf = [],
SecondHalf = [],
receive
    {Pid1, Msg} -> FirstHalf = Msg;
    {Pid2, Msg} -> SecondHalf = Msg
end,
```

This will first assign `[]` to `FirstHalf` and `SecondHalf` variables, and then try to match this with the first message that arrived, as **variables in Erlang cannot be re-assigned**. The second message is ignored as received is only used once. The first result probably isn't an empty list and therefore it will fail with a `badmatch` error. Instead, it seems you mean to perform parallel execution of the merge an collect the results afterwards. You could write:

```
FirstHalf = receive {Pid1, Msg1} -> Msg1 end,
SecondHalf = receive {Pid2, Msg2} -> Msg2 end,
```

This will collect the first half and then the second half.

---

(1) Actually, a qualified call can in fact be executed by **another** module, or more precisely a **newer version** of the module. Qualifying calls to (a loop) function within the same module is a common method to continue execution in a newer version during code upgrades.

Comment: Okay, I updated my code to try both methods you suggested (with exports and all). The first method is doing the same thing. The second method is saying I have a syntax error on the Self= self(), line. I can post the code if you'd like. Thanks for your answer by the way!

Comment: `Self = self(),` is valid, there might be a problem elsewhere in your code. See these results from github: https://github.com/search?q=%22Self+%3D+self%28%29%22+AND+%28spawn+OR+spawn_link%29+extension%3Aerl&type=Code&ref=searchresults

Comment: I was missing the `end` after the `fun`

Comment: Now I'm getting a weird edge case error. I've posted the actual code here: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/5575555, although there's a lot of print statements because I've been trying to figure out why it's not working. If you don't mind taking a look, I'd be happy to clean up the code. The error I'm getting now is a bad match whenever I have an array of size 1.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed the mess in the code you posted in your question. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Now nothing throws but it freezes before it gets the messages. The updated code and the output of running it on `[1, 9, 3, 2, 7, 6, 4, 8, 5]` : https://pastebin.mozilla.org/5575622

Comment: You wrote `receive {Pid, Msg}`. Pid variable is already bound and does not hold the pid of spawned processes. Instead, you need `Pid1` and `Pid2` and `Msg1` and `Msg2`.